# Parsing JSON data stored in AsyncStorage in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have the following data stored in the Async Storage in react native. Can anyone please help me to parse the data from it.

1. Need to display name array alone
2. Need to parse the name array items by looping through it

   {
   "name": [{
           "name": "Ford",
           "models": "Fiesta"
       },
       {
           "name": "BMW",
           "models": "320"
       },
       {
           "name": "Fiat",
           "models": "500"
       }
   ]
   }

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON.parse()` and then get the data you want like so:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(yourObj)

const { name } = obj
console.log(name)
name.forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem)
  //do whatever you want with each elem
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to parse using for loop for the same?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: `AsyncStorage` getItem returns string

**Solution**: When you getItem from `AsyncStorage` it returns `string`.
So you will get your data as string parse it using `JSON.parse` and map to get an array of names.
Like

In case of `AsyncStorage` you need to store it in string format and it will return in string format.
while storing use `JSON.stringify()` to store either object or array. Now to access that Async value get using `getItem` and parse it using `JSON.parse()`

```js
let arr = { "name": [{ "name": "Ford", "models": "Fiesta" }, { "name": "BMW", "models": 320 }, {"name": "Fiat", "models": 500 } ] }
const nameArray = arr.name.map(m=>m.name)
console.log(nameArray)
const nameObjArray = arr.name.map((m)=>{return {"name":m.name}})
console.log(nameObjArray)
```

Comment: I stored the same json in the async storage and accessing it and tried assigning the value directly to the arr here. then it is not working. can u tell me any work around for this

Comment: because you JSON not holding arr directly. you need to access by using `name` which you `key`

Comment: I am assigning entire value directly to the arr here. So ideally it should work ryt? because both arr and value from the storage are same

Comment: in your case, you put array in object with key as `name` but if you want to save array directly in async then use `JSON.stringify(arr)` to store and to get async parse if and use it